# Topos semantics of constructive higher order logic

Tags: ct.category-theory, lo.logic, topos-theory, higher-order-logics

I would like to find a reference that describes the semantics of constructive higher order logic *with function types* in toposes. In particular, it seems that if we are to take function types as primitive, then we need the **definite description operator** $\iota x. P(x)$, which produces a term that satisfies $\exists ! x. P(x) \implies P(\iota x. P(x))$. This is required to prove the principle of unique choice. And if we want the function type to actually be useful this principle is a must. For Isabelle/HOL and HOL Light, the even stronger *indefinite* description operator $\epsilon x. P(x)$ is used, validating choice.

However, I can't work out the semantics of this operator myself. This operator would produce a term no matter whether $P(x)$ actually has a unique solution $x$.
So this would produce a map $\iota : \mathcal P(X) \to X$ in any topos where $X$ is the interpretation of the type of $x$. In the classical case this is fine because we can just case split and assign a junk value. But this doesn't sound possible in an arbitrary elementary topos.

In the literature: the Elephant did mention function types, but it did not talk about definite descriptions at all, and in its definition of the formal system ($\tau$-theory) it did not include function types because we already have powerset types and "we shall keep the logic as simple as possible by leaving them out". This avoids the problem because defining functions as functional relations $\psi : \mathcal P(A \times B)$ makes the principle of unique choice a theorem. In *Introduction to Higher Order Categorical Logic* by Lambek and Scott, there are also no function types.

So, what is the right way of having function types, and ensuring the principle of unique choice? Do we not use definite description, and instead just add an axiom? Or is there another way out? Any reference on this matter is welcome.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you want: are you asking if unique choice holds in an arbitrary Topos? Or do you want to know how one can interpret function types from a given type theory with unique choice in toposes? Something else?

Comment: @cody Neither. I want to know how one can interpret function types with the definite description operator in toposes. If that's not possible though, I would like to hear other ways to introduce unique choice in higher order logic, and the corresponding way to interpret them in toposes.

Comment: Wait can't you interpret a function type $A\rightarrow B$ as $||B||^{||A||}$? Or is the question how to prove that the corresponding semantics exists for all functions?

Comment: @cody If you do that, how is the definite description operator $\iota x. P(x)$ interpreted?

Comment: Ok so that's the question! I need to check Mac Lane & Moerdijk.

Comment: Would you be satisfied with an explanation of definite description which uses the internal dependent type theory of a topos?

Comment: Definite description is definitely true in a topos, but I have never seen it in the form you described above.

Comment: @Nico I understand how it works with dependent types. I'm specifically trying to understand the HOL case because it seems to manage everything without dependency. If we require $\iota$ to additionally depend on a proof then the interpretation is clear. But it breaks the type-term-proof stratification.

Comment: Does Theorem 5.9 of Lambek & Scott's "Introduction to highe-order categorical logic" give you what you're looking for? (Caveat: older books on toposes are generally a bit cavalier about the internal language, for instance, as far as I can tell, the internal language of a topos should have a weird $\mathsf{andalso}$ connective which is like a conjunction but in $\phi \mathbin{\mathsf{andalso}} \psi$ we require $\psi$ to be well-formed only under the assumption that $\phi$ holds. (To write things like $x > 1 \land 1/(x - 1) < 42$.)

Comment: A more careful account of definite description can be found on page 61 of Wesley Phoa's [An introduction to fibrations, topos theory, the effective topos and modest sets](http://www.lfcs.inf.ed.ac.uk/reports/92/ECS-LFCS-92-208/). I remember actually trusting that one when I walked the same path as you are walking now. And the appendix is a very useful resource, page 142 will interest you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Categorical logic texts such as Lambek & Scott's "Introduction to higher-order categorical logic" and Johstone's "Elephant" usually focus on the categorical side of things and are often a bit cavalier about the details of the internal language – enough so to require significant adjustments before one can actually think about implementing it.

Regarding the definite description operator, you can look at Theorem 5.9 of Lambek & Scott, but that's in a section about the internal language, so the authors have the freedom to switch to the categorical side whenever needed, and they do.

Regarding setting up the internal language of a topos qua cartesian-closed category with a subobject classifier, finite coproducts, and coequalizers, I recommend Wesley Phoa's [An introduction to fibrations, topos theory, the effective topos and modest sets](http://www.lfcs.inf.ed.ac.uk/reports/92/ECS-LFCS-92-208/). The precision of detail in the text surpasses other sources that I am familiar with. In particular, the appendix spells out both the details of the formal system, and its interpretation in a topos. The definite description operator is treated on page 61, and in the appendix on pages 134 and 142. As you will see there, the categorical construction of the semantics of the definite description is the most complicated part of the semantics of the internal language of a topos.

Good luck converting a Postscript file to a readable PDF!

Comment: I think `gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=file.pdf -dNOPAUSE file.ps` just does it on my machine. I'm not at a computer now but I strongly feel this reference is just the thing I'm after! If it indeed is I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

As a small addendum to Andrej's answer: note that defining the exponential object $B^A$ as a particular subobject of $A\times B$ is not really "cheating", **if the proof that it is a correct exponential** (up to unique iso) is done cleanly: To get a function

$$A \rightarrow B$$

out of a subset $P: A\times B \rightarrow \Omega$ that satisfies unique choice you can simply use the fact that this represents a function $\overline{P} : 1 \rightarrow B^A$ and use $eval: A\times B^A \rightarrow B$ to get the arrow back out!

Not surprisingly, dealing with the singleton arrow $1_{\{\cdot\}_A} : {\cal P}(A) \rightarrow \Omega $ which picks out the singleton sets of $A$ is going to end up being crucial, and is discussed in the relevant section (Cartesion Closure of Toposes) of Mac Lane & Moerdijk.